# SQL's lead equivalent in KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to achieve something similar to SQL's lead in KQL. The query in SQL would look like below -

```
Select lead(changedBy,1,null) Over (partition by incidentId order by historyId) nextChangedBy
from IncidentHistory IH, Incidents I
where I.IncidentId = IH.IncidentId
and I.UpdatedDate > trunc(sysdate) -30;
```

Could someone let me know how I can achieve the same in Kusto Query Language? I don't see any lead function in KQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least at this point, KQL is more imperative than SQL in this area of windows functions.
We need to [partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/partitionoperator) the data and [order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/orderoperator) it and then we can use [next()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/nextfunction), which is the equivalent for SQL lead().

P.S.
Please note that in SQL there is no need for the elaborate syntax of `lead(changedBy,1,null)`.
Since *1* & *null* are the defaults, `lead(changedBy)` is enough.
Having said that, if needed, KQL does have an equivalent syntax.

```
let Incidents = datatable(incidentId:int, UpdatedDate:datetime)
[
    1 ,datetime(2022-09-15 01:02:03)
   ,2 ,datetime(2022-10-01 04:05:06)
   ,3 ,datetime(2022-10-07 07:08:09)
];
let IncidentHistory = datatable(incidentId:int, historyId:int, changedBy:string)
[
    1 , 10 , "CB1"
   ,2 , 20 , "CB2"
   ,2 , 50 , "CB3"
   ,2 , 60 , "CB4"
   ,2 , 80 , "CB5"
   ,3 , 30 , "CB6"
   ,3 , 40 , "CB7"
   ,3 , 70 , "CB8"
];
Incidents
| where UpdatedDate > startofday(ago(30d))
| join kind=inner IncidentHistory on incidentId
| partition hint.strategy=native by incidentId
  (
    order by historyId asc
    | extend nextChangedBy = next(changedBy)
  )
```

| incidentId | UpdatedDate | incidentId1 | historyId | changedBy | nextChangedBy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022-10-07T07:08:09Z | 3 | 30 | CB6 | CB7 |
| 3 | 2022-10-07T07:08:09Z | 3 | 40 | CB7 | CB8 |
| 3 | 2022-10-07T07:08:09Z | 3 | 70 | CB8 |  |
| 2 | 2022-10-01T04:05:06Z | 2 | 20 | CB2 | CB3 |
| 2 | 2022-10-01T04:05:06Z | 2 | 50 | CB3 | CB4 |
| 2 | 2022-10-01T04:05:06Z | 2 | 60 | CB4 | CB5 |
| 2 | 2022-10-01T04:05:06Z | 2 | 80 | CB5 |  |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32RwU6DQBCG7zzFhBMk1MwupbRr8NB6sA/gyXjYdldYrUsDG5WkD+/QLoWoEZKF/ebPZOb/D9rB1u6N0ta1UICSjt7dQUfG060SxroEHo9U0+qeDtH/OfOu4+ApAHoYJAOKOHI+w9WMZYBMIBeYxr0o4T9FDGfIAOcCM4GLiyj9S5QD5gKXAldx8HwbHCYzP5jW1U337+TVRTNc95W0pVbrTrSuMbacLAEM6Qg3axYOIwP3iI8o8ygd0cKj+YiWHmXhsBmkHi1GNPcoH1Hu0TLst72mE5zgs9KNniYBd9A62bj6RckukmUdpajimKSvtbHwZqwqjLW6+WVYbWH0ifRH6mKcIVyRSzdkDbUvu8JKZz407LqpHCA6W1Y3ilpT7WoxyHZ/Lp1AfzltFVj6bgbLKaf+Hl0z6FOPvwH9TQVAhQIAAA==)